# How to remove id (#) target after refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I have a user flow which the user will fill out a form on index.html and then click on next to go to index.html/#step2

However, I would like the user to go back to index.html, instead of staying on index.html/#step2, if the user hits the refresh button.

Is there any way to force them to go back to index.html?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably do it by setting the location hash to an empty string every time the page loads.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        document.location.hash = "";
    }
</script>
```